# Evaluating a Recursive Expression

Tags: evaluation

**Why does this raise an error**

```
P[0, x_] := 1

P[1, x_] := x

P[n_, x_] := ((2 n - 1)/n)*x*P[n - 1, x] - ((n - 1)/n)*P[n - 2, x]

Simplify[P[n, x]] /. n -> 2

(*$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. >>*)
```

**But this does not**

```
P[0, x_] := 1

P[1, x_] := x

P[n_, x_] := ((2 n - 1)/n)*x*P[n - 1, x] - ((n - 1)/n)*P[n - 2, x]

Simplify[P[2, x]] 

1/2 (-1 + 3 x^2)
```

**More generally how does one generate a list of 1000 polynomials from this recursion? All of the following still seem to raise errors.**

```
Unevaluated@P[n, x] /. n -> {2, 3}

Simplify[Unevaluated@P[n, x] /. n -> {2, 3}]

Simplify[Unevaluated@P[n, x]] /. n -> {2, 3}

{Unevaluated@P[n, x] /. n -> z} /. z -> {2, 3}
```

**If my questions indicate that I am not familiar with mathematica, it is because I am not. :-)**

Comment: without trying (Mathematica is running something at the moment), probably because in trying to `Simplify[P[n, x]]` Mathematica enter the infinite recursion (ie, before the replacement occurs)

Comment: Try `Simplify[Unevaluated@P[n, x] /. n -> 2]`

Comment: Making sure than n is an integer makes it a bit safer.  Define the function with `P[n_Integer, x] := ...`.  But as acl notes, you still can't simplify before you give it a value.

Comment: So, how does one generate a list of 1000 polynomials from this recursion? I try Simplify[Unevaluated@P[n, x] /. n -> 2] and it works, but Simplify[Unevaluated@P[n, x] /. n -> {2,3}] does not work. More importantly, if I use this recursion in more complicated formulas, I have no way of knowing if there will be success.

Comment: To produce lots of them, with your definitions, do eg `Table[P[n, x], {n, 2, 10}]`. As for udnerstanding, given the explanation @ssch gave, you should be able to work out why your attempt didn't work.

Comment: to address your edit, `s/.n->{2,3}` replaces `n` with `{2,3}` in `s`, rather than replacing it first by 2 then by 3 as you apparently expect. Try `g[n]/.n->{2,3}` with `g` undefined

Comment: But, x^2/.x->{2,3} produces a list evaluated at 2 and then 3. It seems that both Table and /. produce lists, but one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: @BobbyOcean that's because `^2` [threads](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) over lists, try for instance `{a,b,c}^3`. While your function does not

Comment: I see. Things are more clear now, thank you very much everyone for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler example where I tell Mathematica to print what it's doing. I `ClearAll[n]` to make sure `n` has no value set.

```
ClearAll[n];
f[0] = 0
f[n_] := f[n - 1]
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 20, $IterationLimit = 20},
 TracePrint[f[n]]
 ]
```

See that there is a bunch of `f[-10+n]` etc, but since `n` is not assigned any value `-10+n` is not zero, and neither is `-12+n` or anything else of the sort.

This means that `f[0]` will never get matched, i.e. it will go on forever, this is a bad thing and you don't want that to happen, for that reason there are global variables [`$RecursionLimit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24RecursionLimit.html) and [`$IterationLimit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24IterationLimit.html) that make sure this doesn't happen.
If for some reason you don't want a limit you can set them to `Infinity` in this case that could crash Mathematica and possibly your computer

Comment: what do you want to link to? the docs for [`$RecursionLimit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$RecursionLimit.html)?

Comment: @acl yes, exactly! For some reason the `$` messes it up

Comment: strange, the first time I edited it it worked in the preview but not when I submitted it; now it works in both (and I've done it two ways to see if it made a difference)

Comment: @acl Thanks! I had similar problem with preview starting of with the right thing but then suddenly changing as I kept typing.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern on the right hand side `P[n_, x_]` matches the new expressions created on the left hand side, namely `P[n - 1, x]` and `P[n - 2, x]` leading to infinite recursion when `n` is a symbol. When you use a concrete value, i.e. n = 2, then it actually uses the end cases, eventually, if the initial n > 0.

Therefore, in the expression `Simplify[P[n, x]] /. n -> 2`, *Mathematica* **first** attempts to resolve `P[n, x]` through the rules you provide, failing into the issue mentioned above.

The second expression `Simplify[P[2, x]]` does not have this issue as explained.

To address your intention, you need to use a procedure that holds P[n,x] unevaluated. For example, `Table` just does that so this works

```
p[0, x_] := 1;
p[1, x_] := x;
p[n_, x_] := ((2 n - 1)/n) x p[n - 1, x] - ((n - 1)/n) p[n - 2, x];
Table[Simplify[p[n, x]], {n, 10}]
```

I used lowercase `p` as it is best practice to use lowercase for user defined symbols, and you don't need the explicit `*` either. Hope this helps.